# Arduino: Why same library is included multiple times

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I couldn't rationalize the reason that why (dependency) library is required when this very library has already been included in the required library itself. For example:

If I want to use SD.h, in the example code, SPI.h is required:

```
   #include <SD.h>  // SPI.h is already included in SD.h
   #include <SPI.h> // why include it here once more
   ...
```

however, if we go into the SD.h and related files, the SPI.h has already been included.

and this is not the only one, ILI9488.h, XPT2046_touchscreen.h, etc. all requires SPI.h when include them.

I have found someone on another topic said at arduino.cc that "if this is not included in the sketch, it (SPI.h) will not be compiled, besides, it is good to tell others that SPI.h is a dependency of the library you included" and I found the last part is especially unreasonable.

Maybe I understood him wrong, but it compiles, and they all worked great without including the SPI.h, **of course, provided that I never used any of the methods from SPI.h.**

However, I am sure I am missing something. I just don't know it and it haunting me ever since my code is working without including the SPI.h.

I appritiate if anyone can provide my some insight about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not using anything from `SPI.h`, don't include it.

Comment: What, exactly, did you find "unreasonable" about the "last part", and why?

Comment: are you sure it's required? does the program stop working if you remove SPI.h?

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik,  it is unreasonable to include all libraries you don't use, just to tell the next reader it is used by someone else's library. And if this is true, to include SD.h, you shouldn't just include SPI.h, you should include: SPI, sd2fat, sdfile, sdfatutil, sdvolume, sd2pinmap, sdinfo. And what if you include Arduino.h, guess how many other .h you should include?

Comment: @user253751 No. I am not sure. But it is a common practice in almost every library example code.

Comment: @tkausl My thought exactly, thanks.

Comment: You asked a question that contains an unfounded assumption. You state you cannot rationalize the reason “why (dependency) library is required,” but nothing in your question indicates the library is required. You write you found “someone” (you should cite sources when quoting people) who wrote “it is good…” That is a recommendation, not a requirement, and it is not a good recommendation. You wrote “it compiles, and they all worked great without including…,” so the include is not a requirement. Quite simply, there is no requirement to include a header that only declares things you do not use.

Comment: Also, “.h” files are header files, not libraries. They declare names, often names of things that are in libraries, but they are not in themselves libraries except for header files that actually provide things directly, such as definitions of static inline functions. The library is actually the object modules that provide the library features, often contained in some form of “library” file such as a “.dylib” or “.so” format. Collectively, all components (header files, object modules, documentation, possibly other parts) forming a library product may be called a library.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thanks for your detailed explaination. I found you comment is the answer to my question in general but only one point is missing: if it is not a requirement, why in the example code provided by the library creator (e.g. sd), SPI.h is included when there is no SPI method is used in the example code? and this is also true in the example code of ILI9488, XPT2046_touchscreen, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino doesn't have makefiles so [the Arduino builder](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.24/sketch-build-process/) scans for #include directives to add the required libraries.

Old version of the build system required to list all libraries in the main ino file. That is why the examples list all the main header files of the libraries used.